# How can I add a line plot in a BOX plot using secondary y axis but same x axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, line

I am trying to add a line plot to my box plot, on secondary y axis, but i am not able to.  what to do? Please help

code for my box plot are:

```
library(ggplot2)
mydata<-read.csv("boxplot2.csv")
mydata$Class <- factor(mydata$Class,labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
p10 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = mydata$Class, y = log(mydata$erosion))) + 
    geom_boxplot()
p10
p10 <- p10 + 
    scale_x_discrete(name = "Mean Annual Precipitation(mm/yr)") +     
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Log Average Erosion Rate(m/My)")
p10 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = mydata$Class, y = log(mydata$erosion))) +
    geom_boxplot(varwidth=TRUE)
p10 <- p10 + 
    scale_x_discrete(name = "Mean Annual Precipitation(mm/yr)") +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Log Average Erosion Rate(m/My)")
```

I want similar figure, but instead of histograms, i will have box plot

[image]

add sample data
% Vegetation erosion Class
0   0.43    1
0   0.81    1
2   0.26    1
3   1.05    1
3   0.97    1
12.76   15.97   2
12.84   17.69   2
11.01   14.76   2
13.44   17.94   2
10.76   10.65   2
7.28    67.47   2
23  120.4   3
21  298.63  3
52  21.4    3
9   64.94   3
50  291.88  3
16  493.98  3
11  183.45  3

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (with some subset or made-up data). You end up with a boxplot because you do `geom_boxplot()` - what is the question exactly?

Comment: I want to add a line plot to my box plot. so the line plot will have secdondary y axis, and same x axis as my box plot

Comment: Idea is to create the same thing like figure above, but instead of histograms, i want box plot, and want the line plot to be as it on secondary y axis

Comment: Post some example data otherwise you will unlikely get any response; or simply search for ggplot2 stacked bar plot.

Comment: secondary y-axis is not supported in ggplot by design, see the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/7860688. You can still plot a second vertical axis with some tweaks. The process is shown on the same link. I can post that an answer as well if you think that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify different aesthetics for the geom_line, something like this:

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length, fill=Species)) + 
geom_boxplot() + 
geom_line(aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length, group=1), stat = "summary", fun.y="mean") +
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.))
```